# How to "union" results from a SQL query when working with dynamic variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to basically loop through some SQL code. I have a set of JobID's (just integers) that are pulled from a SQL statement like this

```
select jobId from tblJobs_List
```

And I need to somehow set them to a variable @jobId and use this variable in my large SQL query below (notice the end of the query in the WHERE clause references @jobId).  I understand I could use a cursor but when I do that, the result sets produced are separate.  They're not "unioned".  I need to somehow union the results.  Any ideas here?

```
select
    a.fkJobID as 'JobID',
    d.EmailAddress, 
    d.SubscriberID,
    b.CustomObjectName as 'Data Extension Name',
    cl.EventDate as 'Last Clicked',
    op.EventDate as 'Last Opened',
    null as 'DEField1',
    null as 'DEField2',
    null as 'DEField3',
    null as 'DEField4',
    null as 'DEField5',
    null as 'DEField6',
    null as 'DEField7',
    null as 'DEField8'
from tbljobs_lists a with (nolock) 
    inner join dbo.CustomObject b with (nolock) on a.CustomObjectID = b.CustomObjectID
    inner join CXXXXXXX._Sent c with (nolock) on c.JobID = a.fkJobID
    inner join CXXXXXXX._Subscribers d with (nolock) on d.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID
    LEFT JOIN (select Q1.* from (select cl.SubscriberID, cl.EventDate, RANK() 
        over (partition by cl.SubscriberID order by cl.EventDate desc) as 'Rank'
        FROM CXXXXXXX._Click cl) Q1 where Q1.[Rank] = 1) cl on cl.SubscriberID = d.SubscriberID
    LEFT JOIN (select Q1.* from (select op.SubscriberID, op.EventDate, RANK() 
        over (partition by op.SubscriberID order by op.EventDate desc) as 'Rank' 
        FROM CXXXXXXX._Open op) Q1 where Q1.[Rank] = 1) op on op.SubscriberID = d.SubscriberID
where a.CustomObjectID is not null and a.fkJobID = @jobid
```

Comment: Wait, just thought of this.  I could write to a temp table.

Comment: why not just `JOIN`  to this table `tblJobs_List` in your query ?

Comment: Try to replace this `tbljobs_lists a` with this `tbljobs_lists a inner join tblJobs_List jl ON a.fkJobID=jl.jobId` and take away the `and a.fkJobID = @jobid`

Comment: That comment above: +1    but if you have to loop, then use a cursor

Answer (score 1):

Using a JOIN like @Squirrel said (or something similar, like an IN or EXISTS) is best unless there's a good reason not to.

If you need to use a loop, store the Job IDs in a table variable, with an IDENTITY column. Use the IDENTITY column as the loop controller. Create a couple variables.  Create a temp table first and have the loop INSERT the values before outputting after the loop.

```
DECLARE @LoopNo INT
     ,@MaxLoopNo INT
     ,@JobID INT

CREATE TABLE #JobIDs (
    LoopNo INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    JobId INT NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    ...
)

INSERT INTO #JobIDs
    (JobId)
SELECT JobId
FROM tblJobs_List

SET @LoopNo = 1
SET @MaxLoopNo = (SELECT MAX(LoopNo) FROM #JobIDs)

SET @JobID = (SELECT JobId FROM #JobIDs WHERE LoopNo = @LoopNo)

WHILE @LoopNo <= @MaxLoopNo
BEGIN

     INSERT INTO #TempTable
     SELECT [Your query here]

     SET @LoopNo = @LoopNo + 1
     SET @JobID = (SELECT JobId FROM #JobIDs WHERE LoopNo = @LoopNo)

END

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable
```

Again... much better and more efficient if you can JOIN, IN, or use EXISTS. That will build the data in a single run instead of once for each record in the first data set.